# Data is not being returned in holder of adapter

Tags: android, retrofit2, adapter

I  am using retrofit to call Data. Following is my pojo

```
public class DataList {
@SerializedName("pariyojanaId")
@Expose
private Integer pariyojanaId;

@SerializedName("projectStatus")
@Expose
private String projectStatus;

@SerializedName("heading")
@Expose
private String heading;

@SerializedName("projectNumber")
@Expose
private Integer projectNumber;

@SerializedName("fieldTitle")
@Expose
private String fieldTitle;

@SerializedName("targetedGroup")
@Expose
private String targetedGroup;

//getter setter
}
```

Following is my retrofit class

```
pariyojanaInterfaces = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(PariyojanaInterface.class);
    Call<DataList> call = pariyojanaInterfaces.getData(memberId);
    Log.e("urll",call.request().toString());

    call.enqueue(new Callback<DataList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DataList> call, Response<DataList> response) {
            datas = Collections.singletonList(response.body());
            ItemListAdapter itemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(context, datas);
            holder.rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            holder.rv.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DataList> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

My adapter is being set but the value that is set is null. The following is my adapter class's bindView holder

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position) {

    datas = dataList.get(position);
    //Log.e("datasss", datas + "");
    holder.txtPariyojanaId.setText(String.valueOf(datas.getPariyojanaId()));
    holder.txtProjectStatus.setText(String.valueOf(datas.getProjectStatus()));
    holder.txtHeading.setText(String.valueOf(datas.getHeading()));
    holder.txtFieldTitle.setText(datas.getFieldTitle());
    holder.txtTargetedGroup.setText(datas.getTargetedGroup());
    Log.e("datahead","" + datas.getHeading() );

}
```

When i print the log, the data that is being printed is null. I dont think there is anything wrong with my pojo and there are data in url as well. Can anybody please help me solve this problem? I dont know why am i getting null.

Comment: call `itemListAdapter .notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: `PariyojanaId` lolz. Anyway, try to add if(response.isSuccessFull()) { code to set data} else { show error message }

Comment: @Farrokh
hello i tried this way
Inside BindHolder,
            lekhaDrillModel = posts.get(position);
 itemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(context, datas);
set linear layout

    holder.rv.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
pariyojanaInterfaces = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(PariyojanaInterface.class);
Call<DataList> call = pariyojanaInterfaces.getData(memberId);
 call.enqueue(new Callback<DataList>() {
     onResponse:

         datas = (List<DataList>) response.body();
         itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     }
Null pointer exception at 
return dataList.size();

Comment: print your `response.body()` and see what's returned

Comment: @Farrokh it is returning the ofject of datalist [nirc.com.gwp.organizationaluser.management.model.Pariyojana.DataList@16d51968]